# Un tracked files are being deleted every git push

Tags: java, git, properties, openshift, gitignore

To avoid mixing our staging properties and our production properties, we maintain a properties template file which is part of the repository. For each instance we create a properties file using the template, with the specific values and add the properties file to the .gitignore list.

I tried to do the same with an openshift. I created the properties files to `app-root/repo` instance but it looks like before the git push this directory is being deleted.

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you git push to openshift your app-root/repo directory is deleted.  You should create those files inside your app-root/data ($OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR) directory, then create symlinks either in your git repo, or in a deploy action_hook to those files from wherever you need them in app-root/repo, similar to how it is done in this file for wordpress for the uploads directory etc: https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy

Answer (score 0):

Did you `git add` the files and directories that you want to be tracked by git?

You might also want to check the `.gitignore` file as well as your git index to ensure files are not exlucded via `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`

Comment: The properties files are server specific and there is no point in adding it to the repository.
The template files are part of the repository.